# cx_Freezeでexe化したPytorchを使用したpythonスクリプトのエラーについて

Tags: python, python3, pytorch, cx-freeze

初めまして。とても困っているので誰か助けてください。
pytorchを使用したpythonプログラム(test2.pyとする)をcx_Freezeでexe化して、生成されたexeファイルを実行したところ、

```
"c:\~~~\torch\__init__.py",line 102, in<module>
 from torch._C import *
importError:DLL load failed:指定されたモジュールが見つかりません。
```

上記のようなエラーが発生します。自分でも調べてみましたが、まったくわからない状況です。
pythonは3.6を使用しています。

exe化用のsetup.pyの中身は次のようにしています。

```
import sys
import os
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable

base = None

if sys.platform == "win32":
    base = "Win32GUI"

os.environ['TCL_LIBRARY'] = r"C:/Miniconda3/envs/my_Project2\tcl/tcl8.6"
os.environ['TK_LIBRARY'] = r"C:/Miniconda3/envs/my_Project2\tcl/tk8.6"

setup(  name = "sample",
version = "1.0",
description = "123",
executables = [Executable("test2.py", base=base)])
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ setup.py ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

Comment: もしかしたら、パス区切りに '/' を使っているからかも？ '\' への統一を試してみてください。[QuickIR を cx_Freeze で Windows の EXEファイルにしてみた（２）](https://y-naito.ddo.jp/index.php?categ=1&id=1479535167)　あとは何か必要なライブラリが入っていないかPATHが通っていないか、関係は無さそうですが__name__が__main__でないことへの対処不足とか。[QuickIR を cx_Freeze で Windows の EXEファイルにしてみた（１）](https://y-naito.ddo.jp/index.php?categ=1&year=2016&month=11&id=1479521523)

Comment: あとは、解決していないようですが、この辺の記事が参考になれば。[Pytorch on Windows gives ImportError](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50264129/9014308)、[from torch._C import * (ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found. #4518](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/4518)、[Help to detect import errors for PyTorch on Windows](https://gist.github.com/peterjc123/21143c0c9426a025618260dde5b6219a)

Comment: ありがとうございます！試してみます。